# What are the possible singular fibers of an elliptic fibration over a higher dimensional base?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, nt.number-theory, reference-request

An elliptic fibration is a proper morphism $Y\rightarrow B$ between varieties such that the fiber over a general point of the base $B$ is a smooth curve of genus one. 
It is often required for the morphism to be flat, but I am open minded about it. 
In order to save your valuable time,  I will first summarize my understanding of the current status and will  then ask my question.

1. If the elliptic fibration admits a section, it is birationally equivalent to a (singular) Weierstrass model.
2. The singular fibers of an **elliptic
   surface** have been classified by
   **Kodaira** and it is closely related to
    ADE extended Dynkin diagrams. There are 9 types of singular fibers including two infinite series.
   Kodaira classification also
   determines the monodromy around each
   singular fiber.  Kodaira
   classification is also reproduced by 
   **Néron** and there is a famous
   algorithm by Tate (called **Tate's algorithm**) which helps
   determining the type of singular
   fibers for a Weierstrass model.
3. In the case of an **elliptic
   threefold**, **Rick Miranda** considers flat resolutions of Weierstrass models. He has a
   classification of singular fibers that results from his analysis.
   He looks at  '**collisions of
   singularities**' at the intersection of
   two divisors of the  discriminant
   locus. He assumes several strong 
   conditions like normal crossing of
   the discriminant locus and  a well
   defined $j$-invariant. He often blow-up the base to get rid of "bad collisions''. He classifies the fibers that appears over the remained "good collisions''. There are 7 non-trivial types of collisions and 5 of them lead to non-Kodaira fibers including an infinite family.
4. Miranda's analysis has been generalized
   by **Michael Szydlo** in his  Phd thesis
   at Harvard under the supervision of
   Barry Mazur. He considers collisions for higher dimensional elliptic fibrations. However, this part of
   thesis has not been published  (but he has a published
   paper on the part of his thesis that
   deals with elliptic fibrations over
   non-perfect residue fields). He assumes the same
   conditions as Miranda and shows that
   in higher codimension, there are a 
   finite number of types of
   non-Kodaira fibers resulting from collisions of singular fibers. Actually his list his similar to the one of Miranda except for one case where they do their blow-ups in different order and (therefore) end up with different fibers.

So here is my question:

> What else is known
>   about the possible fibers of a  higher
>   dimensional elliptic fibrations? Is there a hope to get a classification which does not assume normal crossing? If not, why?
>   Non-trivial examples of non-Kodaira and non-Miranda fibers are also welcome and examples of non-flat fibration as well.

The reason why I won't ask for normal crossing is because geometrically it is not a natural thing to ask. After all, the discriminant of a Weierstrass equation is of the form $\Delta=4 f^3+27 g^2$.  This is not really an invitation to ask for normal crossing... Moreover, in many cases relevant for  applications to string theory, the normal crossing condition will not hold.